# What is the advantage of moving Groups in Organization Units in AD environment beside organizing?

Tags: windows, group-policy, groups

I know the advantage of using OUs (organizing and GPOs).with OUs you can organize your users and computers, assign group policy to them, and deligate control over a set of users and computers. But what about groups ?
What is a benefit of puting groups in an OU beside organizing? Does GPOs affect groups? What would change if I move a group from one OU to another one?

Answer (score 1):

The advantages are:

1. Organizing your Active Directory objects.
2. [Delegating administration of Active Directory](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780779%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)